# Mongoose $in operator not working in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to make a query where it matches a specific value of an array. Not all the values of the array but only one. I know in mongo there is a $in operator so you can match 1 value of the array.

I have written my code something like this:

```
const getSearch = async (req,res) => {
    try{
        //query = { establishment: { name: "foodtruck" }, configuration: { name: "lineal" } }
        console.log(query)
        let doesExist = await Kitchen.find({ "establishment": { "name":  { "$in": ["foodtruck","salon"] } }})
       console.log(doesExist)
    }catch(err){
        throw err
    }
}
```

In my local mongo i have different objects that matches the establishment name. Here they are:

```
db.kitchens.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6084ca4c49ddab30473a7396"), "anafes" : { "quantity" : "1" }, "norms" : [ "norm5", "norm4" ], "availableDays" : [ "4/26/2021", "4/27/2021", "4/28/2021", "4/29/2021", "4/30/2021", "5/1/2021", "5/10/2021", "5/11/2021", "5/12/2021", "5/13/2021", "5/14/2021", "5/15/2021", "5/16/2021", "5/17/2021", "5/18/2021", "5/19/2021", "5/2/2021", "5/20/2021", "5/21/2021", "5/22/2021", "5/3/2021", "5/4/2021", "5/5/2021", "5/6/2021", "5/7/2021", "5/8/2021", "5/9/2021" ], "created_at" : ISODate("2021-04-25T01:26:29.542Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-04-25T01:26:29.542Z"), "deleted_at" : null, "establishment" : { "name" : "delivery" }, "dimensions" : { "name" : "40" }, "configuration" : { "name" : "lineal" }, "pictures" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6084ca4c49ddab30473a7397"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619315274721.jpg" } ], "timePrices" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6084ca4c49ddab30473a7398"), "time" : "perWeek", "price" : "5000" } ], "check_in" : { "from" : "00:00", "to" : "00:00" }, "check_out" : { "from" : "00:00", "to" : "00:00" }, "ovens" : { "name" : "convection", "brand" : "adidas" }, "location" : { "city" : "Buenos Aires", "province" : "Buenos Aires", "street" : "Teodoro Garcia", "number" : "1930", "coords" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6084ca4c49ddab30473a7399"), "lat" : "-34.5650491", "lng" : "-58.4415115" } ], "floor" : "9", "postal" : 1426 }, "type_of_time" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6084ca4c49ddab30473a739a"), "time" : "perWeek" } ], "host" : ObjectId("605f4e36d8281726d9be3ad3"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876791"), "anafes" : { "quantity" : "1" }, "norms" : [ "norm2", "norm3", "norm8" ], "availableDays" : [ "4/30/2021", "5/1/2021", "5/10/2021", "5/11/2021", "5/12/2021", "5/13/2021", "5/14/2021", "5/15/2021", "5/16/2021", "5/17/2021", "5/18/2021", "5/19/2021", "5/2/2021", "5/20/2021", "5/21/2021", "5/22/2021", "5/23/2021", "5/24/2021", "5/25/2021", "5/26/2021", "5/27/2021", "5/28/2021", "5/29/2021", "5/3/2021", "5/30/2021", "5/31/2021", "5/4/2021", "5/5/2021", "5/6/2021", "5/7/2021", "5/8/2021", "5/9/2021", "7/1/2021", "7/10/2021", "7/11/2021", "7/12/2021", "7/13/2021", "7/14/2021", "7/15/2021", "7/16/2021", "7/17/2021", "7/18/2021", "7/19/2021", "7/2/2021", "7/20/2021", "7/21/2021", "7/22/2021", "7/23/2021", "7/24/2021", "7/25/2021", "7/26/2021", "7/27/2021", "7/28/2021", "7/29/2021", "7/3/2021", "7/30/2021", "7/31/2021", "7/4/2021", "7/5/2021", "7/6/2021", "7/7/2021", "7/8/2021", "7/9/2021" ], "created_at" : ISODate("2021-04-28T23:56:46.101Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-04-28T23:56:46.102Z"), "deleted_at" : null, "establishment" : { "name" : "foodtruck" }, "dimensions" : { "name" : "50" }, "configuration" : { "name" : "general" }, "pictures" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876792"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619654809186.jpg" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876793"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619654809259.jpg" } ], "timePrices" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876794"), "time" : "perDay", "price" : "10000" } ], "check_in" : { "from" : "10:00", "to" : "12:00" }, "check_out" : { "from" : "15:00", "to" : "17:00" }, "ovens" : { "name" : "static", "brand" : "adidas" }, "location" : { "city" : "buenos aires", "coords" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876795"), "lat" : "-34.5659098", "lng" : "-58.43880350000001" } ], "province" : "buenos aires", "street" : "Olleros", "number" : "1870", "floor" : "4", "postal" : 1426 }, "type_of_time" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("6089f8a7bda5898d50876796"), "time" : "perDay" } ], "host" : ObjectId("605f4e36d8281726d9be3ad3"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d663"), "anafes" : { "quantity" : "1" }, "norms" : [ "norm1", "norm2", "norm4" ], "availableDays" : [ "4/30/2021", "6/1/2021", "6/10/2021", "6/11/2021", "6/12/2021", "6/13/2021", "6/14/2021", "6/15/2021", "6/16/2021", "6/17/2021", "6/18/2021", "6/19/2021", "6/2/2021", "6/20/2021", "6/21/2021", "6/22/2021", "6/23/2021", "6/24/2021", "6/25/2021", "6/26/2021", "6/27/2021", "6/28/2021", "6/29/2021", "6/3/2021", "6/30/2021", "6/4/2021", "6/5/2021", "6/6/2021", "6/7/2021", "6/8/2021", "6/9/2021" ], "created_at" : ISODate("2021-04-29T00:47:45.376Z"), "updated_at" : ISODate("2021-04-29T00:47:45.376Z"), "deleted_at" : null, "establishment" : { "name" : "foodtruck" }, "dimensions" : { "name" : "50" }, "configuration" : { "name" : "lineal" }, "pictures" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d664"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619659217736.jpg" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d665"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619659217747.jpg" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d666"), "url" : "https://hood-bucket-2021.s3.sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/images/1619659217668.jpg" } ], "timePrices" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d667"), "time" : "perDay", "price" : "5000" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d668"), "time" : "perWeek", "price" : "15000" } ], "check_in" : { "from" : "07:00", "to" : "08:00" }, "check_out" : { "from" : "14:00", "to" : "20:00" }, "ovens" : { "name" : "convection", "brand" : "super", "model" : "adibas" }, "location" : { "city" : "BUenos aires", "coords" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d669"), "lat" : "-34.5793959", "lng" : "-58.40673389999999" } ], "province" : "Buenos aires", "street" : "Avenida del libertador", "number" : "2550", "floor" : "10", "postal" : 1426 }, "type_of_time" : [ { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d66a"), "time" : "perDay" }, { "_id" : ObjectId("608a09e29eda52a6cdc7d66b"), "time" : "perWeek" } ], "host" : ObjectId("605f4e36d8281726d9be3ad3"), "__v" : 0 }
```

But when I run this query:

```
let doesExist = await Kitchen.find({ "establishment": { "name":  { "$in": ["foodtruck","salon"] } }})
```

it does not match anything, but if I run this query:

```
let doesExist = await Kitchen.find({ "establishment": { "name":  "foodtruck" }})
```

It does match. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, or why the ***$in operator*** is not.
working.
Can someone help me?????????

Comment: Your first query `{ "establishment": { "name":  { "$in": ["foodtruck","salon"] } }}` will match exact object, just try concatenating both the fields with `.` dot notation `{ "establishment.name": { "$in": ["foodtruck","salon"] } }`

Answer (score 0):

```
let doesExist = await Kitchen.find({"establishment.name": {"$in": ["foodtruck","salon"]}})
```